# Comparing $e^{-x}$ to its partial sums.

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

**Context**: Many definite integral problems induce inequalities by involving basic inequalities (such as $\sin x, \cos x$ are each always greater than all their partial sums). So, what about $e^{-x}$?

First off, I know that $$e^x>\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{x^i}{i!}$$ for any natural number $k>0$ and $x>0$.

But what about $e^{-x}?$ Firstly, I feel that the comparison should alternate: $e^{-x} <S_k=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{(-x)^i}{i!}$ when k is even (as the next largest term is being *subtracted* from the partial sum to get $e^{-x}$) and $e^{-x} >S_k$ for odd k.

But then again I feel that $S_k$ is a *partial sum*, so it should intuitively be less than $e^{-x}$.

**How does $e^{-x}$ compare to its partial sums**?

Please keep it to high-school level.

Comment: Check out the Alternating Series Test for some good ideas.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I only got $|S_k-e^{-x}|\leq \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ from there (I saw Wikipedia). The absolute value renders it useless.

Comment: Did you read the proof? It should give a nice description of the even and odd partial sums.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I tried rn, but only got so far as the monotonicity  of the odd and even partial sums. After that the monotone convergence theory was invoked, which is absolutely out of high school level. Sorry for not telling “high school” before.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the first few partial sums?

Comment: Hmmm, without getting into the proof, the MCT says that if a sequence has an upper bound, and is increasing, then it has a limit. (And there's a symmetric statement for decreasing sequences.) Have you drawn a number line and plotted where the odd and even partial sums go?

Comment: Does $e^{-x}\approx\sum\limits_{n=0}^k \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=\frac{e^{-x}\int_{-x}^\infty e^{-t}t^k dt}{k!}$ help?

Comment: @Hyperplane I thank thee. It is solved.

Comment: @insipidintegrator - If you have come up with a solution you like, you should add it as an answer below. Do a nice write-up, so future high schoolers who find your question can benefit from your work.

Comment: Ok, I’ll do it as soon as I can. @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Answer (score 2):

Nice question! Your guess is correct. Here's a fun proof: to show that a function $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$ it's enough to show that $f(0) \ge 0$ and $f'(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$ (e.g. by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)). Consider the sequence of functions

$$f_k(x) = (-1)^{k+1} \left( e^{-x} - \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-x)^i}{i!} \right), k \ge 0$$

We want to show that $f_k(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$. We can do this by induction on $k$: we have $f(0) = 0$ for all $k$, and (this is the key computation!) $f_k'(x) = f_{k-1}(x)$, so once we know that $f_0(x) = 1 - e^{-x} \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$ we're done by induction. The same induction gives the strict inequality $f_k(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Show that the Taylor series of $e^x\cdot  S_k(x)$ is of the form

$$e^x \cdot S_k(x) = 1 + (-1)^k \cdot x^{k+1}\cdot  (\textrm{ series with positive coefficients})$$

$\bf{Added:}$ Interestingly enough, a similar thing happens with the other basic inequalities. For instance, the Taylor series of
$$\frac{1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}}{\cos x}$$
has positive coefficients.